# How ignore space withe in distinct fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I send the request:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test1/_search?q=*193*
```

With body:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
   "aggs" : {
        "distinct_groups" : {
         "terms" : { "field" : "group",  "size" : 500}
    }
}
}
```

And I get this response:

```
    "aggregations": {
        "distinct_groups": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                             {
                    "key": "bank",
                    "doc_count": 4
                },
                {
                    "key": "2",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "3",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "5",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But in field "group" actually saves bank 2, bank 3, bank 5.
How I can get response with only this fields?

my mapping:

https://pastebin.com/V4sPWfAV

example my document look like:

```
{
  "group" : "bank 2",
  "type":"comment",
  "data":"second bank",
  "author":"author 2"
}
```

Comment: Can you post how these document look?

Comment: And also your mapping

Comment: @aclokay Update